# Kali linux нет доступа к графическому режиму

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, kali-linux

Пользовался системой раньше, все было отлично. `Kali` стоит на виртуалке. Сегодня при запуске выбивает окно ввода логина и пароля, после ввода - черный экран и снова это окно. В терминал заходит, но кривое отображение, вместо русских символов квадраты, поэтому большую часть ошибок и результатов команд не вижу. Кодировка стоит `utf-8`

Нагуглил, что нужно удалить 2 файла: `Xauthority` и `ICEauthority`, при удалении пишет, что их нет.

Вот что выдает `startx`
[image: screen]

Логи:
https://c.radikal.ru/c42/2103/7e/33a49e4bd5bf.jpg
https://c.radikal.ru/c29/2103/ac/e2112b678f95.jpg
https://a.radikal.ru/a15/2103/7c/980847b16c2e.jpg
https://c.radikal.ru/c12/2103/09/cd7528f46ec9.jpg
https://a.radikal.ru/a12/2103/d9/9ced8a00f35e.jpg
https://c.radikal.ru/c09/2103/4a/93ff4396cfb6.jpg
https://c.radikal.ru/c07/2103/a8/e52ec86e48f3.jpg

Comment: перед командами удаления переключите локаль. Где то так  `LANG=C rm yourfile`, хоть сообщения будут на английском

Comment: @KoVadim пишет, что нет этих файлов

Comment: ну файлы вроде он не удалил) я не знаю куда пишется логи в kali но хотелось бы увидеть логи ошибок. В них скорее всего будет видно куда копать. Если там есть `journalctl` то выполните `journalctl -p err -b 0` и вывод куданить залейте и дайте сылку

Comment: @Максим посмотрите вопрос, обновил

Comment: Вооо, можно посмотреть в лог файле `/var/log/Xorg.1.log` может что то да скажет. Еше можно смотреть строки только с `WW` или `EE`. А лучше весь лог глянуть

Comment: @Максим добавил скрины лога в вопрос, к сожалению могу только скринами, понимаю, что здесь это неправильно.

Comment: @ClarkDevlin проверти драйвера. В логе нет явных ошибок, но постоянно пишет что не смог определить устроство... Не уверен, но может это оно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как бы банально не было, но дело было в закончившемся месте, это и не давало стартануть графическую оболочку.

Решение:

Расширил в виртуалке диск

Вход в терминал через `ctrl alt f1`

Очистка кэша `sudo apt-get autoclean`

После этого графическая оболочка стартанула и расширил саму файловую систему.